# Tkinter Threading Error: RuntimeError: threads can only be started once

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have created a tkinter GUI in the following structure:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.display_button_entry(master)

    def setup_window(self, master):
        self.f = tk.Frame(master, height=480, width=640, padx=10, pady=12)
        self.f.pack_propagate(0)

    def display_button_entry(self, master):
        self.setup_window(master)
        v = tk.StringVar()
        self.e = tk.Entry(self.f, textvariable=v)
        buttonA = tk.Button(self.f, text="Cancel", command=self.cancelbutton)
        buttonB = tk.Button(self.f, text="OK", command=threading.Thread(target=self.okbutton).start)
        self.e.pack()
        buttonA.pack()
        buttonB.pack()
        self.f.pack()

    def cancelbutton(self):
        print(self.e.get())
        self.f.destroy()

    def okbutton(self):
        print(self.e.get())


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('ButtonEntryCombo')
    root.resizable(width=tk.NO, height=tk.NO)
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

I want to prevent the GUI from freezing when running a function (in the example code it's the function of the ok-button). For that I found the solution of using the thread-module as best practice. But the problem is that when I want to run the code once again, python returns this traceback:

```
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once
```

I'm totally aware of the problem that threads can be only starten once as stated in the error message. My question is: How can I stop a thread to start it a second time or does anybody has a better workaround for preventing the GUI from freezing and pressing a button/running a function multiple times?

BR and thank you
Lorenz

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code will only create one thread and assign its `start` function reference to `command` option.  Therefore same `start()` function will be called whenever the button is clicked.

You can use `lambda` instead:

```
command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.okbutton).start()
```

Then whenever the button is clicked, a new thread will be created and started.

Comment: You've shared another working solution for a similar problem in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450516/i-get-this-error-runtimeerror-threads-can-only-be-started-once-when-i-click-c

Both your solutions work for me, I'm wondering what would be the pertinent differences between the two, and which would be the "best practice"?